# Uniformly distributed differences

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Is there a collection of random variables $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ such that $Y_1=X_1-X_2,~Y_2=X_2-X_3,\ldots,~Y_n=X_n-X_1$, are independently uniformly distributed on $[-1,1]$. How $X$'s should be distributed to achieve this (if possible)?

Comment: What about taking $Y_1,\dots,Y_n\sim\mathrm{Unif}([-1,1])$ independent, and defining $X_1=0$, $X_2=-Y_1$, $X_3=X_2-Y_2 =-(Y_1+Y_2)$, $X_4=X_3-Y_3=-(Y_1+Y_2+Y_3)$, etc.? 

Basically, $-X_j$ being the sum of $j-1$ i.i.d. uniform random variables on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: But then $Y_n=X_n-X_1$ is not uniform, as it is $Y_n=-(Y_1+\ldots+Y_{n-1})-0$, and sum of the uniforms is not uniform.

Comment: Let $n=2$ and you'll see the impossibility.

Comment: My bad, forgot the last one (ie, the cyclicity).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\sum_iY_i=0$. That can only happen for independent variables if they are all almost surely constant. Thus there are no such variables.

Comment: @Did: Since you added "identically distributed": How can this happen for independent variables if they're not identically distribtued?

Comment: Constant random variables are independent of everything else (sorry, I should have commented instead of modifying the answer).

Comment: @Did: Ah, of course. But it would be correct to say "That can only happen for independent variables if they are all almost surely constant"?

Comment: Yes, correct and better than my suggestion.

Comment: Indeed, thank you very much!